# Как использовать абсолютный xPath с условиями в Selenium?

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

Есть `xPath=//*[@id="wl_post_actions_wrap"]/div/div[1]/a[1]` который работает. Но нужно еще проверить обладает ли `<a>` классом `my_move`.
Попытка сделать это так

```
//*[@id="wl_post_actions_wrap"]/div/div[1]/a[1] and not(contains(@class, 'my_like'))
```

Успеха не дала, возможно ли вообще решить задачу таким образом, или нет? Возможно есть способ получив `WebElement` дополнительно проверить его на содержание `my_move`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо делать такой xpath

```
xPath=//*[@id="wl_post_actions_wrap"]/div/div[1]/a[position()=1 and contains(@class,'my_move')]
```